# "Cannot be applied to" in a fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I have created 4 tablayouts in my APP, and each has a layout source file and class. Also i want to add a SwipeRefreshLayout in this fragment.
But there is something wrong when i add`swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(getActivity());`
And `swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);` does'nt work either..
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EMja.png)

fragment:

```
public class tab_ask extends Fragment {
    public CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    public boolean isConnected;
    public static final String NA = "NANA";
    public List<Post> postList;
    public RecyclerView recycler_post;
    public recadapter adapter;
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4ask, container, false);
        recycler_post = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_post);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recycler_post.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recycler_post.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        getData();

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fragment should implement `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` if your want to set it as a listener.

Comment: @X-XEON If my answer helped you please flag it as correct